# Method for User uploading Large ZIP file to server

Tags: file-upload, upload, dropbox, opencart, large-file-upload

I am using OpenCart right now to allow customers to buy products from my website.

Once they have successfully purchased an item, I would like them to be able to upload a large file (preferrably via FTP) to my server. I'm expecting somewhere between 10Mb and 100Mb.

Is this possible and how would you recommend I put this together?

I'm guessing I'd have to create a private directory on my server using the orderID.
**Should I just create an FTP user with write-only access to a specific private directory on the server and ask them to upload '<%OrderID%>.zip' there?**

Or is there a better way of handling this? Should I consider Dropbox, Amazon S3 or even [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)?

Many thanks for any help with this :-)

Comment: I guess this is kinda unconstructive question...that will much better suite for the OpenCart forums... What about: After You have decided what option to use You come back with concrete problem with the implementation?

Comment: I like the fact that this question is being asked. It shows more serious and commercial stores on OpenCart rather than the amateur bloated stores and plugins you see. OpenBay being of course not amateur but role model. I would recommend RackSpace Cloud Files CDN or Amazon S3 - simple to upload.. you could make the digital goods and the upload field available on product page and basically it will AJAX upload the item whilst on the site - you can set expiry-date and times on content too.. so once you have the file you can delete it from the admin panel or the folder itself.